# Move a part of array to another array C#

Tags: c#

I insert a text files with content is

[image]

I want to move the part
***else
{
IpcRegs.IPCCLR.all = abc;
all = pSysInfomData->freq();
}*** to another array. But with my code below. It's always take both lines ***"st->testCount++;
st->testCount = 0;"*** to new array too.

I used Array.Clear to clear the part which I took out of last array. Anyone have better suggest to clear the part which I was copied to new array?

Thank you for you support

```
        var path = textBox1.Text;
        string data = File.ReadAllText(path);
        textBox2.Text = data;
        string[] lines1 = textBox2.Lines;
        int count = 0, countElseStart = 0, countElseEnd = 0;
    
        for (int i = 0; i < lines1.Length; i++)
        {
            if (lines1[i].Contains("else"))
            {
                countElseStart = count;                     
            }
    
            if (lines1[i].Contains("}"))
            {
               countElseEnd = count - countElseStart;      
            }
            count++;
        }
                    
        string[] eLines = lines1.Skip(countElseStart + 1).Take(countElseEnd).ToArray(); 
                    
        Array.Clear(lines1, countElseStart + 1, countElseEnd);
    
        List<string> withOutElsePart = new List<string>();
    
        for (int a = 0; a < lines1.Count(); a++)
        {
            withOutElsePart.Add(lines1[a]);  
        }
        string[] lines = (withOutElsePart.ToArray()).Where(x =>!string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).ToArray();
```

Comment: Have you tried Array.Copy yet? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.copy?view=net-5.0

Not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but the destination needs to be the same size as the source. IE, if new part you want to copy in is 100 items, the space you're copying to in the destination needs to be 100 items.

If it needs to be a different size, then you need something that supports changing sizes, such as List<>.

Comment: I want to take the else's part to read single lines in text. From that, I will draw the shapes and drawText into the shapes. But my problems is with my algorithms, they are not stop on the first "}" after else. They always count to last "}" in the text and skip().Take() all of index. do you have any idea to help to bug it?

Comment: First if all you are doing is using the textbox2 to split the text into lines, you can get rid of that and use File.ReadAllLines (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalllines?view=net-5.0) instead of File.ReadAllText.

Comment: For your first array, from the logic of it is going to only find the very last line that has "else" and the very last "}".

Comment: yes, so do you have any idea to make it stop in the first "}" after else?

Comment: I already tried ReadAllLines. It did not work for the text which I insert in from the my computer. So, this is reason why I just can be use ReadAllText

Comment: Even use Array.Copy, we still need index of the part where we want to copy. But the problems is I can not stop at the first "}" to get the range to copy.

Comment: I just noticed in your example picture for the else code you are stripping, it's missing a } before the else.

You have `pSysInfoData->freq = CMCL_FRENQUENCY_50; else {`. You should have `pSysInfoData->freq = CMCL_FRENQUENCY_50; } else {`

Answer (score 0):

So I read over your logic, and your comment, and I think I understand what you are trying to do... I just need one clarification. Are you trying to strip out all 'else {}' blocks? Or just the else {} block you find? Because depending on your end goal has two slightly different solutions.

So lets start out with just stripping out only the first else:

```
// We don't actually need this in Lines.
string data = File.ReadAllText(path);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
int elseStart, elseEnd;

// First we need to find the first instance else. We'll use string.IndexOf for that.
// If IndexOf returns an number greater than or equal to zero, we found else.
// https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=net-5.0#System_String_IndexOf_System_Char_System_StringComparison_
elseStart = data.IndexOf("else");
// Can 'else' be a different case? 
// If so we might to do data.IndexOf("else", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) instead.

if (elseStart > -1) // We found an else. Now find it's closing brace.
{
    // This is where it gets tricky.
    // What if there is items inside of the else block that have {}?
    // Now we need try and find the correct matching '{' to the end of the else '}'.
    int curlyStart, curlyEnd, nextStart;

    // This should be the first curly after the 'else'.
    curlyStart = data.IndexOf('{', elseStart);
    if (curlyStart > -1)
    {
        nextStart = data.IndexOf('{', curlyStart + 1);
        curlyEnd = data.IndexOf('}', curlyStart);
                
        // We should find our correct curly end if the follow conditions are true:
        // 1. We found a curly end (curlyEnd > -1).
        // 2. We didn't find another curly start (nextStart < 0), or if we did, 
        //    it is at a position later than our current curly end (nextStart > curlyEnd).
        while (nextStart > -1 && curlyEnd > -1 && nextStart < curlyEnd)
        {
            // If this is true, then we found another starting { before the curlyEnd we found.
            // Search for the next curly end, and next curly start.
            nextStart = data.IndexOf('{', curlyEnd);
            curlyEnd = data.IndexOf('}', curlyEnd + 1);
        }

        // Make sure we have a proper end.
        if (curlyEnd > -1)
        {
            // Get everything before the else.
            sb.Append(data.Substring(0, elseStart));
            // Get everything after the else end.
            sb.Append(data.Substring(curlyEnd + 1));

            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

This is just some rough code to give you an idea of the kind of logic you need. There might be better or more efficient code out there.

For the case of there being multiple 'else {}' blocks and you want to strip them out, it's similar logic to the above, except you put most of in a giant while block, and you just strip out one else block at a time. Or you could make a method that takes the string and returns the string with the first else block removed. Then you just call that same function over and over again until it no longer finds any more else blocks.

Edit: I test with your example data (would have been nice if it had just been the text and not a picture). Anyway, correct a couple logic errors in this edit. There is one logic error that I left in: specifically, `sb.Append(data.Substring(curlyEnd + 1));` correctly removes the else {}, but it leaves a blank line behind. For curlyEnd, you might want to find the start of the next line and adjust to using that.

Comment: actually, I think with new else part, I will move it to new array. Because I want to draw else part follow the if{} block. If I move every else{} to one array, it will be duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get the last two lines moved to your other array is because the ending `}` on the last line.

To get what you want with what you have already -- try this:

```
...
        bool inElse = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < lines1.Length; i++)
        {
            if (lines1[i].Contains("else"))
            {
                countElseStart = count;
                inElse = true;                     
            }
    
            if (lines1[i].Contains("}") && inElse)
            {
               countElseEnd = count - countElseStart;
               inElse = false;      
            }
            count++;
        }
...
```

Comment: could you explain that why you put inElse like that?

Comment: 'inElse' is being used as a state - once you find your 'else'.  Then once you find your closing brace (for the 'else') you're no longer in that state and you no longer have to look for another closing brace.

Comment: so what happen if inside the else{} have a for{}? it will also stop at the } of the loop and will not go to the } of the else